# Any way to remove the 512 character limit on Nook Touch notes?

Tags: nook-for-android, nook-simple-touch

The Nook Simple Touch is an android-based eReader. In their interface for reading books, you can highlight a word or set of words, then attach a note to that.

The notes are limited to 512 characters, but you can have an unlimited number of notes for a book. I currently work around the limit by highlighting a word, writing the note, then highlighting the next word and continuing the note.

Is there a way to remove the limit of 512 characters, or increase it to a very large number? My nook is fully rooted, so I imagine it is a simple config file or sqlite entry somewhere, but I don't know where to look.

Comment: It's more likely to be hard coded in to the app, so it would be impossible to modify without modifying the app source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Liam's comment in my question was correct. The max character value is hard-coded into the Reader.apk file. Therefore, the answer to my question is no...

Unless you modify the program itself. I made changes to the file to increase the limit; details can be found at [this xda forum post](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=37343918&postcount=2). Because the solution required programming, I won't post the entire answer here, as programming is outside the scope of the Android site.

Comment: This is *exactly* what I said :angryface:

Comment: I had this answer saved for quite a while and was finishing up the xda post before I submitted the answer. Besides, I give an alternate solution; There's no need to vote me down for that.

Comment: It's the same solution - reprogram the app.

Comment: True, it's the same resolution. But I actually took the time to *do* the reprogramming needed, and I linked to the appropriate posting with the actual solution. And I apologize for posting after you did; I did not see your answer when I posted mine because I had typed up my answer a few hours ago but was waiting to post it until I finished my xda post.

Comment: You get an AJAX popup when there is a new answer, but I will undownvote. EDIT: I can't until the answer it edited.

Answer (score 0):

As the title of this question begins with 'Any' this answer is fully valid:

There is *no* way to do this, as that value will (most likely) be hard coded into the application source code. This means the only way to change it would be to download the app source and edit the value.